# best way to update object in one of many lists

Tags: c#, list, collections, observablecollection

I'm trying to find the best way to update an object which could be in one out of a handful of different list / collections

Example:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Status { get; private set; }

    public MyItem(string name)
    {
        this.Id = new Guid();
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public void UpdateStatus(string status)
    {
        this.Status = status;
    }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> ItemList1;
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> ItemList2;
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> ItemList3;

    public UpdateStatus(Guid id, string status)
    {
        // Figure out which ItemList needs to be updated
        var item = ItemList1.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = ItemList2.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                item = ItemList3.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
                if (item == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Unable to update Status");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        item.UpdateStatus(status);
    }
}
```

I dislike the nested if's so I'm sure there is a better way, but its Friday and my brain is fried :(

I realize that I could add something like this instead of the nested ifs:

```
public MyItem UpdatedStatus(ObservableCollection collection, Guid id)
{
    return collection.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
}
```

or

```
public bool UpdatedStatus(ObservableCollection collection, Guid id, string status)
{
    var item = collection.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
    if (item != null)
    {
        item.UpdateStatus(status);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But it seems like there should be a better way

Any tips?

These collections could have hundreds of items in them with more in the later ones so I'm trying to find the most efficient way to handle the updates.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ for help. Does it work for you as expected?

```
var item = ItemList1.Union(ItemList2)
                    .Union(ItemList3)
                    .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
```

Important:

[Union()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) returns unique  elements, it could be slow on large data sets so consider using [Concat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) for large lists instead"

```
var item = ItemList1.Concat(ItemList2)
                    .Concat(ItemList3)
                    .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
```

Also it worth take a look at the Jon Skeet's `Concat()` implementation from edulinq serie, `Concat()` is really straightforward: ([Full Article](http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/08-Concat.html))

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatImpl<TSource>( 
    IEnumerable<TSource> first, 
    IEnumerable<TSource> second) 
{ 
    foreach (TSource item in first) 
    { 
        yield return item; 
    } 
    foreach (TSource item in second) 
    { 
        yield return item; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the Union take the longest amount of time since it would combine all of the collections into one? Or would it search them in order?

Comment: `Union()` does compare of elements to return unique items results set, so yet it would relatively be slow. But for small data sets this difference could be ignored. if you need more performant solution - use LINQ `Concat()`

Comment: The task defined in the question does not require using `Union`. `Concat` with `FirstOrDefault` will do exactly the same as the code in the question.

Comment: `Concat()` looks better, but won't it still combine all of the items together before checking for the value? I think @MartinLiversage's answer will work better for my needs at this time, since it won't check all of the lists every time.

Comment: @John: Using `Concat` is efficient. No combined collection is created (unless you call `ToList` or something similar). Your own solution, my solution and this `Concat` solution will produce code that uses the same amount of memory and CPU. It is really a matter of taste and readability.

Comment: @MartinLiversage so even if `List1` has 10 items, `List2` has 30 and `List3` has 2,000, and the item I'm searching for is in `List2`, if I used `Concat` wouldn't search in `List3` since it was already found? Or do you mean the compiler optimizes our solutions down to very similar code anyway? Thanks! :)

Comment: @John: Yes, `List3` would never be touched or copied or anything if the item is in `List2`. That is the beauty of LINQ and lazy evaluation. If the lists where iterator blocks that produced elements on the fly there would be no additional storage for the "lists" and `FirstOrDefault` would ask for a new elements until the correct one was found (or the code producing the elements was exhausted).

Comment: @MartinLiversage awesome, I didn't realize that... go LINQ! Wish I could give you both the Accept, already gave upvotes

Comment: @MartinLiversage : You right, this would perform as the initial code, but OP does not asked for more performant solution so `Concat()` woudl be enough, regarding `Union()` - it is just ineteresting know how different LIQ operators are differ even looks the same at the first glance. .

Comment: @sll well I wanted the most efficient method as well, but it looks like since `Concat` only reads until it finds a match this is both less amount of code and as efficient (a little more so since it has less null checks). If you know of any more efficient ways please let me know :)

Comment: @John : `Concat()` has all needed null checks, or what you mean?

Comment: Correct, I meant it doesn't have to double check for `null` between each list, it just "continues" on to the next since it hasn't found a result yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) (`??`) to simplify your code:

```
public UpdateStatus(Guid id, string status) 
{ 
    var item = ItemList1.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id)
        ?? ItemList2.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id)
        ?? ItemList3.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id)
    if (item == null) 
    { 
        Debug.WriteLine("Unable to update Status"); 
        return; 
    } 
    item.UpdateStatus(status); 
}
```

Comment: Man for how many ternary operations I've done with null checks this would have simplified it a lot :)